# .Env file in Django project

Tags: django

I write this lines in .env file in django project to link my project to my Data base
but visual code make a problem to the file

[image]

Comment: But does it cause any issues?

Comment: yes I can't link my project to  data base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "export" from your .env file.

```
DB_NAME=IncomSpendsDB
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD='0000000'
DB_HOST=localhost
```

https://djangocentral.com/environment-variables-in-django/